# What's the difference between /\p{Alpha}/i and /\p{L}/i in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to build a regexp in ruby to match alpha characters in UTF-8 like `ñíóúü`, etc. I know `/\p{Alpha}/i` works and `/\p{L}/i` works too but what's the difference?

Comment: That's odd. According to [this comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), the former should not be available in Ruby.

Comment: Must be out of date because I'm using both in my rails console.

Comment: Looks like it is out of date. Ruby started using a new Regex engine in 1.9, IIRC, so these probably date from then.

Comment: Alright. Well, according [to this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) (which is hopefully not out of date). `\p{Alpha}` is equal to `\p{L&}` for Unicode-aware engines. This character class, contains only those letters, that have lower- and upper-case variants ([see here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)) I don't have a letter at hand that you could use to test this, but it's worth a try if you find one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They seem to be equivalent. (**Edit:** sometimes, see the end of this answer)

It seems like Ruby supports  `\p{Alpha}` since version 1.9. In POSIX `\p{Alpha}` is equal to `\p{L&}` (for regular expressions with Unicode support; [see here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)). This matches all characters that have an upper and lower case variant ([see here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)). Unicase letters would not be matched (while they would be match by `\p{L}`.

This does not seem to be true for Ruby (I picked a random Arabic character, since Arabic has a unicase alphabet):

- [`\p{L}` (any letter) matches.](http://www.rubular.com/r/IGWHWnzhgX)
- [Case-sensitive classes `\p{Lu}`, `\p{Ll}`, `\p{Lt}` don't match.](http://www.rubular.com/r/Gr8HE07Y3p) As expected.
- [`p{L&}` doesn't match.](http://www.rubular.com/r/2slOJAxPKc) As expected.
- [`\p{Alpha}` matches.](http://www.rubular.com/r/fv6ucYm6l9)

Which seems to be a very good indication that `\p{Alpha}` is just an alias for `\p{L}` in Ruby. On Rubular you can also see that `\p{Alpha}` was not available in Ruby 1.8.7.

Note that the `i` modifier is irrelevant in any case, because both `\p{Alpha}` and `\p{L}` match both upper- and lower-case characters anyway.

**EDIT:**

A ha, there is a difference! I just found [this PDF](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ruby3_extract_regular_expressions.pdf) about Ruby's new regex engine (in use as of Ruby 1.9 as stated above). `\p{Alpha}` is available regardless of encoding (and will probably just match `[A-Za-z]` if there is no Unicode support), while `\p{L}` is specifically a Unicode property. That means, `\p{Alpha}` behaves exactly as in POSIX regexes, with the difference that here is corresponds to `\p{L}`, but in POSIX it corresponds to `\p{L&}`.

Comment: Thanks. I just realize what you pointed out about the `i` modifier.

Comment: @BishmaStornelli it seems like I wasn't entirely right. see my edit ;)