# How to use regex to swap number position in a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say I have a string `"2foo9 8bar5"`. I need to swap the two numbers wrapping each word. The result should look like this `"9foo2 5bar8"`.

I can do it with the following code.

```
def swap_num(str)
  str = str.gsub(/(\d)(\D+)(\d)/, '\3\2\1')
end
```

But if I have a string like this `"2foo9 8bar5 3+=_1"`, this `swap_num` method will swap the numbers for the last part `"3+=_1"` as well, which is not what I want. I only want to swap numbers wrapping WORDS, not any CHARACTERS.

I have tried the following, but didn't work.

```
def swap_num(str)
  str = str.gsub(/(\d)([a-zA-Z]+)(\d)/, '\3\2\1')
end
```

Any way to do it with a simple regex? Thanks!

Update:

Sorry guys. I made a mistake and `str = str.gsub(/(\d)([a-zA-Z]+)(\d)/, '\3\2\1')` actually works my purpose. But it wouldn't work if I use double quotes like this `"\3\2\1"`.

Thanks, @Robin for pointing out my original code actually work. And also thank @Cary Swoveland and @Andie2302 for providing 2 new solutions to me! Really appreciate it!

Comment: How does your attempt fail?

Comment: It just doesn't change anything at all and output the exact same string I put in.

Comment: It seems okay to me: https://ideone.com/UM8FfO Can you show more code then?

Comment: My mistake. Actually this work. It didn't work when I use double quotes `"\3\2\1"`. And it outputted this result `"\u0003\u0002\u0001 \u0003\u0002\u0001 3+=_1"`. However, it works when I use single quotes. Why is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The working regex is:

```
(\d)(\p{L}+)(\d)

str = str.gsub(/(\d)(\p{L}+)(\d)/, '\3\2\1')
```

\p{L} ... Matches a character from the Unicode category “letter” (any letter character of any language)

Comment: Actually I just found my original code `str = str.gsub(/(\d)([a-zA-Z]+)(\d)/, '\3\2\1')` would do what I expected, which is only swapping the numbers when they are wrapping `[a-zA-Z]+`. I didn't get the right output because I used double quotes like this `"\3\2\1"` instead of single quotes.

Comment: Could you give an explanation of what `\p{L}` does? It would be helpful for other people too.

Comment: Edmund, suppose you try to match letters of the word `str = "Passé"`. Let's first try `r = /[a-zA-Z]+/`, `str[r] #=> "Pass"`. Not so good. We need a regex that will work with Unicode characters. We could use `/\p{L}+/`, `/\p{alpha}+/` or `/[[:alpha:]]+/`. These all return "Passé". However, some  prefer the brevity/flexibility of any of these to `/[a-zA-Z]+/` (or `/[a-z]+/i`) when matching what are expected to be only ASCII characters. See the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517100/whats-the-difference-between-palpha-i-and-pl-i-in-ruby) for a fuller discussion.

Comment: The `\p{L}` just confuses the issue in this case. This problem is not about unicode so there's no reason for this.

Comment: @pguardiario unicode is never wrong. It meets the requirements of swap numbers wrapping words.

Answer (score 6):

You could do this:

```
R = /
    \b       # match a word boundary
    (\d+)    # match ?= 1 digits, capture in group #1
    ([a-z]+) # match >= 1 lower case letters, capture in group #2
    (\d+)    # match >= 1 digits, capture in group #3
    \b       # match a word boundary
    /ix      # case indifferent (/i) and extended mode (/x)

def flip_numbers(str)
  str.gsub(R) { $3+$2+$1 }
end

flip_numbers("2foo9 8bar5")
  #=> "9foo2 5bar8"
flip_numbers("233foo91 8bar5")
  #=> "91foo233 5bar8" 
flip_numbers("2foo9 8bar5 3+=_1")
  #=> "9foo2 5bar8 3+=_1"
flip_numbers("a2foo9 8bar5 3bat7c")
  #=> "a2foo9 5bar8 3bat7c"
```

Note that in the last example, because of the word boundary requirement, the numbers in `a2foo9` and `3bat7c` are not exchanged.

Each matched string is passed to `gsub`'s block, which computes the replacement for that string. We could write the block as:

```
{ |s| <code here> }
```

where the block variable equals the matched string. In the first example that would be:

```
s = "2foo9"
```

We wish to replace this with:

```
"9foo2"
```

The contents of the three capture group are contained in the global variables:

```
$1 #=> "9"
$2 #=> "foo"
$3 #=> "2"
```

The replacement string is therefore:

```
$3+$2+$1 #=> "2foo9".
```

Hence the block is written:

```
{ |s| $3+$2+$1 }
```

but since we don't use the block variable `s` in this calculation, we can omit `|s|` from the block. That's good practice, as reduces the chance of error and also tells the reader that the block variable is not used.

The expression `$3+$2+$1` could instead be made an argument of `gsub`, but in that case it must be written:

```
"2foo9 8bar5".gsub(R, '\3\2\1')
  #=> "9foo2 5bar8"
```

or

```
"2foo9 8bar5".gsub(R, "\\3\\2\\1")
  #=> "9foo2 5bar8"
```

Here the choice is purely stylistic.

Comment: Thanks @Cary Swoveland . But can you explain to me how the block `{ $3+$2+$1 }` work? I am new and never used the dollar sign to do this before.

Comment: I provided an explanation.